# Displaying products on home page

Tags: php, magento, product, magento-1.5

I've been searching around on Google to find an accurate tutorial that explains how to display products on the home page but so far nothing is working!

The latest products block doesn't work; the only thing that I've managed to get working is a single link to a product which is not very attractive.

Anyone know how to display products, featured products, etc. on the home page?

ps. I'm using Magento 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage/) [excellent](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/add_featured_products_to_home_page) [tutorials](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page) [on](http://www.blastedthing.com/magento/homepage/mag-display-products-on-home-page-magento-video/) [the](http://vimeo.com/1070986) web on this topic.  I would recommend the Inchoo blog post as first option.

If you have specific issues, please report back with a full trace of the errors that you are receiving, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages you could, say, set catalog/category/view/id/10 to have the default route resolve to a category with entity id of 10.

You'll need to consider duplicate content (SEO) issues if you want this to show elsewhere on your site.